# Lotus Notes opens wrong mailbox

Tags: mailbox, lotus-notes

I have a Lotus Notes client that keeps trying to open the wrong mailbox when clicking the Mail icon on the default home page.

The server document for the user is correctly pointing to the users mailfile e.g. *mail/user.nsf*, the workspace has the correct mail file. But the *notes.ini* is showing *mail/wronguser.nsf* . I have changed the *notes.ini* to point the correct mail file but it just changes back next time the Notes client opens. What could be causing this?

**Note:** The version is Lotus Notes 8.5.2 Fix pack 1 client and version 6.5 server.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried replacing the bookmarks.nsf, you should only need to delete it and as long as bookmark.ntf exists a new one should be created when the client is launched. The notes.ini should have the correct mailfile in it before the client is started.

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings of the current location document.